# Include arbitrary files in RST

Tags: restructuredtext, docutils

The `DocUtils include` directive allows the inclusion of arbitrary text into an `RST` document. The problem is that the implementation restricts the specified files to be in the same document as is the location of the included file. This makes the use of includes for external files that may be used in many documents difficult. The standard DocUtils solution is to use something called `Standard Definition Files`. Unfortunately, these require anyone using this facility to have the DocUtils source code involved which will affect every end-user who needs this facility. Needing source code is not an acceptable solution for people who are not programmers and are only trying to use Docutils, possibly in an environment such as Sphinx. Is there any other work-around for this situation?

Comment: Can you cite your references with links? Does Sphinx's [`literalinclude` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) do what you need?

Comment: @Steve Piercy, What references do you want? I checked `literalinclude` and it suffers from the same problem as `include`. It can only retrieve a file from the current document whereas I want to retrieve a file from an arbitrary location in the file system.

Comment: Would something like this help? https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-remoteliteralinclude/

Comment: What is the error if you use an include path pointing to a file in a different directory? Which command do you use to convert the rST document?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`literalinclude` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) using `..` to navigate up and around the filesystem. For example:

`.. literalinclude::  ../../external-to-project-directory/src/somefile.py`

Will include `somefile.py` as literal code into your documentation.

If you want to parse the code as rst, then use `include` instead.

Comment: Steve Piercy, the documentation for `literalinclude` includes the following statement: `The file name is usually relative to the current file’s path. However, if it is absolute (starting with /), it is relative to the top source directory`. This implies to me that the document being included must be in the document directory hierarchy. Am I wrong in my interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

With Docutils, you can include files from anywhere in the filesystem.
Absolute paths start from the filesystem root, relative paths are expanded relative to the work directory (from which you start the `docutils` or `rst2html5` command line front end).

In Docutils 0.21, the root directory for included files will become configurable using the [root-prefix](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#root-prefix) setting.